# Placeholder glitches on Chrome and Safari browser showing perfect for mozilla browser

Tags: html, css

I create login form, have email and password fields both form place changes position in chrome and safari browser

```css
/*LOGIN*/
.login-container{
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
.login-form:before{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 50px;
 height: 800px;
 width: 800px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 border-radius: 900px;
}
.login-form{
 flex-basis: 575px;
 flex-grow: 0;
 position: relative;
 background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 padding: 75px;
}
.login-form:after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 130px;
 height: 600px;
 width: 600px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 border-radius: 600px;
}
.login-form .band-identity{
 height: 85px;
 width: 85px;
 border-radius: 20px 35px 20px 35px;
 background-color: #000;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 border: 5px solid #fff;
}
.login-form .brand-heading{
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-basis: 0;
}
.login-form h3.page-title{
 font-family: poppins-regular;
 font-size: 24px;
 background-color: #000000;
 border-radius: 100px;
 padding: 12px 30px 17px 30px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-flex;
 margin-right: -150px;
 float: right;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.login-container h4.page-title{
 font-family: poppins-regular;
 font-size: 24px;
 background-color: #000000;
 border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
 padding: 20px 30px 25px 30px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-flex;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100px;
 right: 0px;
 
}
.login-form h1 span{
 font-family: poppins-medium;
 font-size: 26px;
 color: #000;
 display: block;
 line-height: 40px;
}
.login-form h1{
 font-family: poppins-bold;
 color: #324ee1;
 font-size: 42px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 35px 0px 60px 0px;
}
.login-form h1:after{
 content: "";
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 27px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: 10px solid #ffc000;
 position: absolute;
}
.login-banner{
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-basis: 0;
}
.login-banner img{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
form.material-form{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
.material-form .form-group{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.material-form label{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: avenir-roman;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.material-form a.btn-send-message{
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.material-form #errorHandling{
 display: none;
}
.material-form .form-group i {
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px;
 top: 45px;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
 font-size: 20px;
}
.material-form .form-group p {
 font-family: ubuntu-regular;
 font-size: 18px;
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.material-form input,
.material-form textarea {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 35px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 100%);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 0px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  font-size: 20px;
  resize: none;
  font-family: poppins-regular;
}
/* .material-form input:focus, 
.material-form input:valid,
.material-form textarea:focus,  
.material-form textarea:valid { */
.material-form input:focus, 
.material-form textarea:focus{
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #324ee1;
}
.material-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.material-form input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}
a.link-forgot-password {
 font-family: avenir-roman;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
 margin: 10px 0px;
 display: block;
}
a.link-forgot-password:hover {
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.btn-login{
 margin-top: 35px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.btn-login:hover{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #3149c9;
 margin-top: 32px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn-login:hover:after{
 bottom: -1px;
 opacity: 0.85;
}
.btn-login:hover i{
 animation: 1s iconbounce forwards;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.php" id="login" name="login" method="post" class="material-form py-sm-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">email</label>
                <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="errorHandling"  placeholder="companysupport@gmail.com" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">password</label>
                <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" aria-describedby="errorHandling" placeholder="**********" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <a href="forgot-password.php" class="link-forgot-password">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-style-1 btn-lg btn-login">login <i class="fas fa-arrow-right ml-3"></i></button>                                
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It is showing perfect for mozilla browser[image]

It glitches as below images for chrome and safari browsers as below[image]

Thank You

Comment: how is it a glitch if you transform it? `::-webkit-input-placeholder { translateY(-20px);}`

Comment: Transform translateY(-20px) for up-down placeholder position on focus input tag animation.

Comment: the one is default state and the other on is focus state both are different what you expect form that?

Comment: On focus state placeholder text goes up with  animation and when on focus down text goes down with animation, in default state leave as it is like mozilla/firefox browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the following rules if you don't want to alter its position

```
.material-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.material-form input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```css
/*LOGIN*/

.login-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.login-form:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 50px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 900px;
}

.login-form {
  flex-basis: 575px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
  padding: 75px;
}

.login-form:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 130px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 600px;
}

.login-form .band-identity {
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  border-radius: 20px 35px 20px 35px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.login-form .brand-heading {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.login-form h3.page-title {
  font-family: poppins-regular;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 12px 30px 17px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: -150px;
  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.login-container h4.page-title {
  font-family: poppins-regular;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
  padding: 20px 30px 25px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 0px;
}

.login-form h1 span {
  font-family: poppins-medium;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.login-form h1 {
  font-family: poppins-bold;
  color: #324ee1;
  font-size: 42px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 35px 0px 60px 0px;
}

.login-form h1:after {
  content: "";
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 27px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 10px solid #ffc000;
  position: absolute;
}

.login-banner {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.login-banner img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

form.material-form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.material-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.material-form label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: avenir-roman;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.material-form a.btn-send-message {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.material-form #errorHandling {
  display: none;
}

.material-form .form-group i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 45px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.material-form .form-group p {
  font-family: ubuntu-regular;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.material-form input,
.material-form textarea {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 35px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 100%);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 0px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  font-size: 20px;
  resize: none;
  font-family: poppins-regular;
}


/* .material-form input:focus, 
.material-form input:valid,
.material-form textarea:focus,  
.material-form textarea:valid { */

.material-form input:focus,
.material-form textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #324ee1;
}

a.link-forgot-password {
  font-family: avenir-roman;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  margin: 10px 0px;
  display: block;
}

a.link-forgot-password:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.btn-login {
  margin-top: 35px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn-login:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3149c9;
  margin-top: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn-login:hover:after {
  bottom: -1px;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.btn-login:hover i {
  animation: 1s iconbounce forwards;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.php" id="login" name="login" method="post" class="material-form py-sm-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="errorHandling" placeholder="companysupport@gmail.com">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" aria-describedby="errorHandling" placeholder="**********">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <a href="forgot-password.php" class="link-forgot-password">Forgot your password?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-style-1 btn-lg btn-login">login <i class="fas fa-arrow-right ml-3"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code to support all browsers:

Example:

```
 .input-email::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #9b9b9b;
  }

  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  .input-email:-moz-placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #9b9b9b;
  }

  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  .input-email::-moz-placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #9b9b9b;
  }

  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  .input-email:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #9b9b9b;
  }

  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  .input-email::-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #9b9b9b;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove this code

> -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
>     transform: translateY(-20px);

from

```
.material-form input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```css
/*LOGIN*/
.login-container{
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
.login-form:before{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 50px;
 height: 800px;
 width: 800px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 border-radius: 900px;
}
.login-form{
 flex-basis: 575px;
 flex-grow: 0;
 position: relative;
 background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(50, 78, 225, 0.20) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
 padding: 75px;
}
.login-form:after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 130px;
 height: 600px;
 width: 600px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 border-radius: 600px;
}
.login-form .band-identity{
 height: 85px;
 width: 85px;
 border-radius: 20px 35px 20px 35px;
 background-color: #000;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 border: 5px solid #fff;
}
.login-form .brand-heading{
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-basis: 0;
}
.login-form h3.page-title{
 font-family: poppins-regular;
 font-size: 24px;
 background-color: #000000;
 border-radius: 100px;
 padding: 12px 30px 17px 30px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-flex;
 margin-right: -150px;
 float: right;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.login-container h4.page-title{
 font-family: poppins-regular;
 font-size: 24px;
 background-color: #000000;
 border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
 padding: 20px 30px 25px 30px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-flex;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100px;
 right: 0px;
 
}
.login-form h1 span{
 font-family: poppins-medium;
 font-size: 26px;
 color: #000;
 display: block;
 line-height: 40px;
}
.login-form h1{
 font-family: poppins-bold;
 color: #324ee1;
 font-size: 42px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 35px 0px 60px 0px;
}
.login-form h1:after{
 content: "";
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 27px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: 10px solid #ffc000;
 position: absolute;
}
.login-banner{
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-basis: 0;
}
.login-banner img{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
form.material-form{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
.material-form .form-group{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.material-form label{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: avenir-roman;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.material-form a.btn-send-message{
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.material-form #errorHandling{
 display: none;
}
.material-form .form-group i {
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px;
 top: 45px;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
 font-size: 20px;
}
.material-form .form-group p {
 font-family: ubuntu-regular;
 font-size: 18px;
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.material-form input,
.material-form textarea {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 35px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 calc(100% - 2px), #324ee1 100%);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 0px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  font-size: 20px;
  resize: none;
  font-family: poppins-regular;
}
/* .material-form input:focus, 
.material-form input:valid,
.material-form textarea:focus,  
.material-form textarea:valid { */
.material-form input:focus, 
.material-form textarea:focus{
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #324ee1;
}
.material-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.material-form input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.material-form textarea:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 10px;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
a.link-forgot-password {
 font-family: avenir-roman;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
 margin: 10px 0px;
 display: block;
}
a.link-forgot-password:hover {
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.btn-login{
 margin-top: 35px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.btn-login:hover{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #3149c9;
 margin-top: 32px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn-login:hover:after{
 bottom: -1px;
 opacity: 0.85;
}
.btn-login:hover i{
 animation: 1s iconbounce forwards;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.php" id="login" name="login" method="post" class="material-form py-sm-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">email</label>
                <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="errorHandling"  placeholder="companysupport@gmail.com" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">password</label>
                <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" aria-describedby="errorHandling" placeholder="**********" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <a href="forgot-password.php" class="link-forgot-password">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-style-1 btn-lg btn-login">login <i class="fas fa-arrow-right ml-3"></i></button>                                
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```